# SAS Delete group if there are missing observations

Tags: sas

In my sas data set there are groups, i.e. id and I want delete groups with missing values in a certain variable.

For example I have this sas data set:

```
data have;
    input v1 v2 v3 id;
datalines;
9 7 210 1
0 6 .   1
9 3 320 2
6 1 .   1
9 4 432 2
;
run;
```

I tried this:

```
/*Order by id*/ 
proc sort data=have;
     by id;
run;

/*Select no missing observations by id*/
data=want;
set=have;
if cmiss(of _all_) then delete;
run;
```

However this code does not exclude id's with missing values. It delete missing values.

Comment: What is your desired result for the given input?  If I follow your logic both ids will be deleted because of missing values on rows 2 and 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm.  You can use `proc sql` for this:

```
proc sql;
    delete from have
    where exists (select 1 from have have2 where have.id = have2.id and (have2.v1 is null or have2.v2 is null or have2.v3 is null);
```

Answer (score 1):

One idea might be to use a double DOW loop.  First to check for any missing values and then a second one to output the records for the ids with no missing values.

```
data have;
  input v1 v2 v3 id;
datalines;
9 7 210 1
0 6 .   1
9 3 320 2
6 1 .   1
9 4 432 2
1 2 333 3
;
```

You will need to sort as in your example.

```
data want ;
  do until (last.id);
    set have;
    by id;
    anymissing=max(anymissing,cmiss(of v1-v3));
  end;
  do until (last.id);
    set have;
    by id;
    if not anymissing then output;
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just dont want to have lines with missing Columns in your result dataset. So why delete, just exclude them when writing result-dataset or overwrite source-Dataset.:

```
data have;/*overwriting my have dataset instead of deleting lines*/
set have;
if not cmiss(of _ALL_);
run;
```

When you want to remove all lines for a group if only one line has a missing value you can do this, Store an ID if it has no value and then dont write any line with that id, and you just get ID lines you want as result. Important is that the ID with missing value is first in dataset, but that should be that way because of proc sort:

```
data want;
retain x;
set have;
if cmiss(of _ALL_) then
x= id;
if x ne id;
run;
```